# Writing and Reading data to and from Socket on keyPressed()

Tags: java, python, sockets, networking, processing

I have a Processing code that reads from and writes to a Python app via Sockets. I want it to write on keyPressed and read on keyReleased actions.

Problem is, there is no action being performed on those two events. It refuses to connect to the Socket on key actions.

Here is the java code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
String result;
String status;
String reply;

void setup(){
    size(1000, 450);
    textFont(createFont("Arial", 20));
    result = "You Said!";
    reply = "He Replied: ";
    status = "...";
}
void draw(){
    background(0);
    text(result, 0, 50);
    text(reply, 0, 150);
    text(status, 0, 250);
}
public void keyPressed() {
  status = "PRESSED";
  try {
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8089);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    outToServer.writeBytes(result + '\n');
    outToServer.flush();
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    println(e);
  }
}
public void keyReleased () {
  status = "RELEASED";
  try {
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8089);
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));  
    reply = inFromServer.readLine();
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    println(e);
  }
}
```

The socket connection isn't happening at all. The status string isn't changing. Is there anywhere I'm going wrong? Logically this seems correct.

Comment: The code doesn't appear to be valid Java for one. Next, if you're sending char data, then I'd use a PrintWriter or PrintStream. Also, I'm not familiar with processing, but many libraries will require you to use background threads for background processes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This isn't technically Java, it is Processing. And the code works well when I put it all together, this keyPressed and keyReleased thing is creating the problem. It works fine otherwise.

Comment: Ah, then you should lose the [tag:java] tag.

Comment: The code is essentially Java, cuz I ported it from there.

Comment: How is key pressed been called?

Comment: @MadProgrammer it gets called when I click the applet window.

Comment: So now your blocking the main UI thread everytime a key event occurs

Comment: I don't think that's happening cuz I think Processing manages that in the backend. But even if it did, it's fine.
See, I have a STT service running. That creates a string which is stored in `result`
Now, when I want to send that line to my Python app, I click.
When I release, Python returns a result.
And in reality, my main event thread continues running. Clicking has seemingly no effect on the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Client](http://www.processing.org/reference/libraries/net/Client.html) and [Server](http://www.processing.org/reference/libraries/net/Server.html) in Processing. See the following two mini apps:

```
import processing.net.*;

Server s;
Client c;
String reply = "n/a";

void setup() {
  size(300, 200);
  s = new Server(this, 8089);
}

void draw()  {
  background(50);
  // Receive data from client
  c = s.available();
  if (c != null) {
    reply = c.readString();
  }

  fill(255);
  text(reply, 100, 100);  
}
```

and the client code

```
import processing.net.*;

Client c;
String msg;

void setup() {
  size(300, 200);
  c = new Client(this, "127.0.0.1", 8089);
}

void draw() {
  background(204);
}

void keyPressed() {
  msg = "Hello world";
  c.write(msg + "\n");
}
```

You need to start the server first.

Verify it's not due to the key event handling methods, by trying out this super simple Processing sketch:

```
import java.net.*;

try {
  Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8089);
}
catch (Exception e) {
  println(e);
}
```